# No puedo usar omnifaces con Maven

Tags: java

Al tratar de usar omnifaces tengo el siguiente mensaje de error :

> Error resolving project artifact: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.omnifaces:omnifaces:pom:2.7.3 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.7.3/omnifaces-2.7.3.pom.
>   Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. for project
>   org.omnifaces:omnifaces:jar:2.7.3

Answer (score 3):

Parece que hace poco Maven no da soporte a los HTTP por ser inseguros y obliga a que se use el queridisimo y mas encriptado HTTPS.

Si recibes dicho error en teoria con tan solo cambiar las URLs de Maven Central con sus respectivos HTTPS deberia funcionar.

Ejemplos:

Cambiar http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ a --> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Cambiar http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ a --> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Si por necesidad obligada necesitas que sea el protocolo http puedes indicarlo como http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/ al cual llaman **insecure endpoint**.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que estas utilizando una versión de maven anterior a la`3.2.3` que utilizan la ruta http y apache anuncio que desde el 13 de Enero de 2020 se dejaría de utilizar http(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/) para quedarse con https, para solventar el problema tienes algunas opciones:

1. Actualizar maven a la versión `3.2.3` o superior (actual `3.6.3`) (recomendada)
2. Coloca una configuración global para que tu version de maven ya haga peticiones unicamente al repositorio https MAVEN_HOME\conf\settings.xml  mas información aquí (http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)

   ```
   <settings>         
    <mirrors>
      <mirror>
     <id>internal-repository</id>
     <name>Maven Repository Manager running on https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</name>
     <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
     <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
   </mirror>
   ```
3. colocar a cada proyecto en el pom el siguiente fragmento:

   ```
   <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
         <id>Central Maven repository</id>
         <name>Central Maven repository https</name>
         <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
   ```

Comment: Genial , use la opción 3 )  agregué en el archivo pom el fragmento de código y funcionó de maravilla. Gracias.